# Android wifi login via hotspot landing page, using Facebook API, browser not fully communicating with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-wifi, android-browser

We have created a wifi hotspot, using a Mikrotik Routerboard. **Everything works fine from laptops**, i.e. When the user opens a browser, they get redirected to the hotspot landing page we have created. There they can login with facebook. When we try to connect with facebook from an android mobile device, it does not work. We have noticed that when we connect to the wifi network from the android device, a notification pops up which when touched it displays a browser with the hotspot landing page. Now we have realised that this browser that gets automatically popped up is **not the native Android browser** and we have not installed any app that may be doing this. Basically, we have narrowed down the problem to the following:

- If the user touched the popup notification to open the landing page and login to facebook from there, they normally get redirected to facebook, but upon successful facebook login, when they get redirected to the landing page, the facebook API function `FB.getLoginStatus` returns `status = uknown`.
- If the user ignores the popup notification and they open the native android browser, facebook login procedure works perfectly and `FB.getLoginStatus` returns `status = connected`.

So, from android, the facebook login procedure will work, only if the user launches the native android browser application.

It looks like the problem is not on our landing page, since users can login from laptops and the **android native browser**. What kind of a browser is invoked by the wifi notification popup and how can we tame it?

This is how we initialise the facebook api:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{FacebookAppId}',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.12'
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        $(document).trigger('fbload');
        });

    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

This is how we redirect to facebook login:

```
window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?client_id=<our_app_id>&scope=email&redirect_uri=" + 
    encodeURIComponent("our_redirect_uri") + "&state=" + 
    encodeURIComponent('{"username":"' + document.getElementById("facebook_username").value + '","password":"' + 
    document.getElementById("facebook_password").value + '"}');
```

This is the function we use to get the facebook login state and facebook details:

```
function checkLoginState() {

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

            /* In case of successful login. */
            if (response.status == "connected") {
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(newresponse) {
                    document.getElementById('social_method').value = "facebook";
                    document.getElementById('social_id').value = newresponse.id;
                    document.getElementById('social_name').value = newresponse.name;
                    document.getElementById('regemail').value = newresponse.email;
                    /* Login to box*/
                    document.getElementById('btnConnect').click();
                });

            }

        });
```

Comment: George did you have any joy resolving this? im currently experiencing an identical problem